# sending email from android app (Genymotion Emulator)

Tags: android, email, android-emulator, email-attachments

I'm new to Android!!! and I'm a bit stuck! 
I'd like to know which is the code to send email with attachments through an android application. Looking around a bit, I read that it is not possible to send emails from the emulator but it is never specified which emulator they used. I use Genymotion, so is it possible to send email through an app or opening the already present app for emails,  with this emulator?  How can I do this adding also attachments?

Thanks a lot to everyone!

Matteo

Comment: After I set up an email account on the emulator I was able to send an email with an attachment. Initially I had a problem because I had incorrect permissions on the attached file.